# support vector machine values

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, computation-models

Does anybody knows how to calculate w1 and w2 and b . 
I have the formula but I have no idea where those numbers come from .
my question has solution so it is not a home work because the solution of question is included I only want to learn how the numbers come from .[image]

Comment: To make it more clear, replace w1 and w2 with a and b and replace x1 and x2 with x and y to get the line equation ax+by+c=0. So w1 and w2 are the coefficients of x1 and x2.

Answer (score 0):

From your figure, assume the orange is $x_1=mx_2+n$, then substituting point $(5,5)$ or $(9,1)$ will give you: $x_2=-x_1+10$. Similarly, you can know that the blue line is $x_2=-x_1+7$. Then the dotted line in the middle (which is exactly the separating hyperplane) is
\begin{align}
&x_2=\frac12((-x_1+10)+(x_2=-x_1+7))=x_2=-x_1+8.5\\
\Longrightarrow\;
&x_2+x_1-8.5=0\\
\Longrightarrow\;
&w_1=1,w_2=1,b=-8.5.
\end{align}